# Connecting to a local Database through Lambda functions AWS

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql

I am trying to connect to a local instance of MYSQL through AWS lambda functions.
Is there something I am missing? I want anyone who accesses an API endpoint to trigger this lambda function, and show them all entries in the Database. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong!

This is my Lambda Function

```
import pymysql
import json
# TO zzip code all up after it is finished, Use
# zip -r9 ${PWD}/function.zip


# Lambda Permissions:
# AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

# Config values
endpoint = 'localhost'
username = 'root'
password = ''
database_name = 'test'

# Connection
conn = pymysql.connect(host=endpoint, user=username,
                       passwd=password, db=database_name)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from i5')

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # 2. Construct body of the response object
    transactionResponse = {}
    transactionResponse['message'] = 'Hello From Jareds lambda function'
    transactionResponse['tickets'] = json.dumps(rows)

    # 3. Construct HTTP response object
    responseObject = {}
    responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
    responseObject['headers'] = {}
    responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(transactionResponse)

    return responseObject
```

Errors from cloudwatch

```
[ERROR] OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol)")
File "/var/task/handler.py", line 18, in <module>
    passwd=password, db=database_name)
  File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
    raise exc
```

Comment: You have MySQL running on your local laptop/PC, and you want AWS Lambda to connect to that database?

Comment: If you want to connect to a database from Lambda - you should consider using an Amazon RDS instance.

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` resolves to the local computer. AWS Lambda functions run in some managed server environment inside an Amazon data center. Within the Lambda environment `localhost` is going to resolve to that server (or actually the Docker container the Lambda function is in). When you trigger a Lambda function invocation, that code is not running on your local computer, so there is no way for it to connect to your local database at the address `localhost`.

You would have to expose your local database on the Internet and access it via the Lambda function from your public IP address. I don't recommend actually doing that unless you understand the security implications of exposing a database on the Internet and understand how to secure it accordingly.

Comment: There are a ton of ways of achieving the desired task.
One could use fixed IP and route configuration, proxy, etc. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @iwaduarte If you have a better answer then by all means post that as a new answer to this question. My answer is purely about the resolution of the `localhost` loopback address. My answer implies that they would have to change the `localhost` address to something else, such as a fixed IP address. My answer does not say at any point that a fixed IP address would not be a solution. It only says that using the `localhost` address cannot work.

Comment: "When you trigger a Lambda function invocation, that code is not running on your local computer, so how would it connect to your local database?"

What would the excerpt above imply?

Comment: @iwaduarte I've updated my answer based on your feedback.